# How to add different objects to a queue using a for loop

Tags: java, queue

I want to add 10 records of type CustomerQueue to a CustomerQueue array located within the CustomerQueue itself the print out that array. The problem is that it keeps 'enqueueing' to position 0 because for each CustomerQueue object, the rear is reset to 0. Is there any workaround for this?

Main:

```
CustomerQueue cQ = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cQ = new CustomerQueue(1, 0, false);
        cQ.enqueue(cQ);
        System.out.println(cQ.arrivalTime);
    }
System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cQ.array));
```

Constructor:

```
public CustomerQueue(double aT, double tT, boolean pM) {
    aT = (double) (Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    this.arrivalTime = aT;
    this.tallyTime = tT;
    this.paymentMethod = pM;
    capacity = 500;
    front = 0;
    rear = -1;
    count = 0;
}
```

Enqueue:

```
public void enqueue(CustomerQueue cQ) {
    if (isFull()) {
        System.out.println("OverFlow\nProgram Terminated");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    rear = (rear + 1);
    array[rear] = cQ;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
CustomerQueue cQ = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cQ = new CustomerQueue(1, 0, false);
        cQ.enqueue(cQ);
        System.out.println(cQ.arrivalTime);
    }
```

to

```
CustomerQueue cQ = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        CustomerQueue subQueue = new CustomerQueue(1, 0, false);
        cQ.enqueue(subQueue);
        System.out.println(subQueue.arrivalTime);
    }
```

Do comment if your requirement is something else than this.